# Is there a way to omit a certain route when using the mapbox directions API?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm using the MapBox directions API to show and calculate the distance between several waypoints. The thing is, this routes are for big trucks, and MapBox generates a route where big trucks can't go through (A tiny one way bridge). Legally, only cars can go through. Is there a way to tell the direction's API to skip that bridge and generate an alternative, longer route?

Answer (score 4):

The only exclusion options currently available in the Mapbox Directions API are for ferries, tolls, and motorways. You can not exclude with waypoints or areas at this time. Where available, Alternative routes may be requested by passing the alternatives=true parameter. If you wish to create custom routes, use the Map Matching API to make a request that will snap your desired coordinates to parts of the network you wish to route on.